# How to check image source for a given tr

Tags: jquery

I have got a table with around 50 rows, now what I want is to check the image source of selected tr from table who has given custom attribute, I am not sure how can I do it efficiently, please guide in right direction,

html

```
"<tr fruit-id='" + someID+ "' class='Row' onclick='DoSomething(" + someID + ")'>" +
"   <div class='Row'>" +
"       <td class='Cell CellInfo'>" +
"           <div class='Title'>" + FruitTitle + "</div>" +
"       </td>" +
"       <td class='Cell CellIcon'>" +
"           <div><img src='" + src + "' alt='" + alt + "' /></div>" +
"       </td>" +
"   </div>" +
"</tr>"
```

**Now I got someID, and I want to know it's Img Src**

Maybe like,

`$("tr[fruit-id=" + someID + "]").closest('tr '..` not sure how to get image src here :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), since the `img` is a descendant element of the target tr

```
var src = $('tr[fruit-id="' + someID + '"]').find('img').attr('src')
```

or use a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
var src = $('tr[fruit-id="' + someID + '"] img').attr('src')
```

Also if you are doing this in the `DoSomething` method, then I would recommend using a jQuery event handler instead of an inline handler.

Otherwise instead of passing the `someID` to the method, you can pass the reference to the dom element itself by passing `this` to the method like

```
"<tr fruit-id='" + someID+ "' class='Row' onclick='DoSomething(this)'>"
```

then

```
function DoSomething(tr){
    var src = $(tr).find('img').attr('src')
}
```

Comment: why are you using `tr[fruit-id=` instead of using the unique id `someID`? and won't this break if he has more than 1 image?